# I want to add elements in array dynamically in following format

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two arrays, 1 column and 2 rows. I want to add rows array data to columns array dynamically as per shown in code. For time being i have taken hard coded values in these arrays i have one add button.
Actually i want to render n*n matrix which has drop down buttons.

I have defined one method on add button and using for loop i pushed columns array to rows array.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import './Table.css';


export class Table extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            columns: ['state 1', 'state 2', 'state 3', 'state 4', 'state 5', ''],
            emptyheader: [''],
            rows: [
                ['state 1', 'state 2', 'state 3', 'state 4', '', ''],
                ['state 2', 'state 2', 'state 3', 'state 4', ' ', ''],
                ['state 3', 'state 2', 'state 3', 'state 4', ' ', ''],
                ['state 4', 'state 2', 'state 3', 'state 4', ' ', ''],
                ['state 5', 'state 2', 'state 3', 'state 4', ' ', '']
            ],

            selectedTeam: ''
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>

                <table align="center">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            {this.state.emptyheader.map((emptyheader, i) =>
                                <td >{emptyheader}</td>
                            )}
                            {this.state.columns.map((column, i) =>
                                <td >{column}</td>
                            )}
                        </tr>

                        {this.state.rows.map((row, i) =>
                            <tr key={i}>
                                {row.map((cell, i) =>
                                    (i < 1) ? (
                                        <td scope="row" key={i}>{cell}</td>
                                    ) : (
                                            <td>
                                                <select>
                                                    <option value="forward">Forward</option>
                                                    <option value="reverse">Reverse</option>
                                                    <option value="NA">NA</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </td>
                                        )
                                )}
                            </tr>
                        )}
                    </tbody>
                </table>


            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Table;
```

I want to render n*n matrix

Comment: Can you add codesandbox example, where we can look and fix it? Because above code doesn't show `handleChange`.

Answer (score 2):

Can you show your `handleChange` method

I think it should be something like

```
this.handleChange = (e) => {
    let { rows } = this.state;
    rows.push(newElement);
    this.setState(rows);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very obvious what you are trying to do based on the question, but if you want to dynamically add rows and columns, try the following snippet. In particular look at the `addColumn` and `addRow` methods.

```js
class Table extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      columns: ['state 1', 'state 2', 'state 3', 'state 4', 'state 5', ''],
      emptyheader: [''],
      rows: [
        ['state 1', 'state 2', 'state 3', 'state 4', '', ''],
        ['state 2', 'state 2', 'state 3', 'state 4', ' ', ''],
        ['state 3', 'state 2', 'state 3', 'state 4', ' ', ''],
        ['state 4', 'state 2', 'state 3', 'state 4', ' ', ''],
        ['state 5', 'state 2', 'state 3', 'state 4', ' ', '']
      ],

      selectedTeam: ''
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.addColumn = this.addColumn.bind(this)
    this.addRow = this.addRow.bind(this)
  }
  
  handleChange() {}
  
  addColumn() {
    const { columns, rows } = this.state;
    columns.push('');
    this.setState({ columns });
  }
  
  addRow() {
    const { rows } = this.state;
    rows.push([]);
    this.setState({ rows });
  }

  render() {
    const { rows, columns } = this.state;
    const displayRows = rows.map(row => [...row, ...new Array(columns.length - row.length)]);

    return (
      <div>
        <table align="center">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              {this.state.emptyheader.map((emptyheader, i) =>
                <td >{emptyheader}</td>
              )}
              {this.state.columns.map((column, i) =>
                <td >{column}</td>
              )}
            </tr>

            {displayRows.map((row, i) =>
              <tr key={i}>
                {row.map((cell, j) =>
                  (j < 1) ? (
                    <td scope="row" key={j}>{cell}</td>
                  ) : (
                      <td>
                        <select disabled={i === j - 1}>
                          <option value="forward">Forward</option>
                          <option value="reverse">Reverse</option>
                          <option value="NA">NA</option>
                        </select>
                      </td>
                    )
                )}
              </tr>
            )}
          </tbody>
        </table>
        
        <button onClick={this.addColumn}>add column</button>
        <button onClick={this.addRow}>add row</button>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Table />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

EDIT: Updated snippet to reflect @GS7's comment.

EDIT: Updated to disable diagonal drop down lists

Comment: how can i use only columns array to render n*n matrix? Suppose if i push another state to columns array i.e. state 6 then new row and new column should get added? how can i achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean without changing the state of `rows`? If so, you can compute the additional values in `render`.

Comment: yes without changing the state of rows. but the values present in this rows array are not numeric  these are string values and i will get this array through props. based on this array i want to render matrix in n*n form?

Comment: I've updated the snippet to calculate `displayRows` in the render method. Hope that helps.

Comment: i have another issue: i want to disable diagonal drop down buttons. is it possible? i tried but couldn't find the solution.if u give the solution it will be very helpful.

Comment: See updated snippet. I made the `select`'s `disable` attribute conditional.

Comment: thank u. it helped me a lot.  i just want to know that can i push one react component to array. that array is defined in another react component?